# Vb.net Identify how much specific colors in an image

Tags: vb.net, image, colors

is there a vb.net code to identify how much specific color(brown,yellow,green) in an image? Like I have an image of a leaf and i want to identify how much yellow colors, brown colors and green colors of that image so i can have a result that either the leaf is:
dead-ALMOST BROWN
healthy-ALL GREEN
unhealthy-YELLOWISH

Do i need to convert the image first to other types like bitmap/threshold ?
DO you have any reference for this? Thanks a Lot in advance